# Php function and variable with code

Tags: php, function, variables, scope

I want to understand why this code give me:

```
function query_select_array($col1, $col2, $col3, $table, $code) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if ($result = $this->myconn->query($query)) {
        while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $a = $obj->$col1;
            $b = $obj->$col2;
            $c = $obj->$col3;
    $code = '$a - $b - $c <br>'; //I want pass this code with function, this is for test..
    eval("\$code = \"$code\";");
            echo $code;
        }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
}
```

This:

> 1996 - La fondazione - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis
>   temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et
>   ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!
>
> Marzo 1999 - Ufficio laboratorio a Lavagna - Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente,
>   totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde,
>   sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!
>
> Dicembre 2012 - Spostamento a Sestri Levante - Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente,
>   totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde,
>   sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!
>
> Febbraio 2016 - Nuovo Sito - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis
>   temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et
>   ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!

But this:

```
function query_select_array($col1, $col2, $col3, $table, $code) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    $code = '$a - $b - $c <br>'; //If I pass $code with the function i get the same effect...
    if ($result = $this->myconn->query($query)) {
        while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $a = $obj->$col1;
            $b = $obj->$col2;
            $c = $obj->$col3;
            eval("\$code = \"$code\";");
            echo $code;
        }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
}
```

Generate the unwanted:

> 1996 - La fondazione - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis
>   temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et
>   ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!
>
> 1996 - La fondazione - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis
>   temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et
>   ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!
>
> 1996 - La fondazione - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis
>   temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et
>   ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!
>
> 1996 - La fondazione - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis
>   temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et
>   ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!

Can any one help me?

Comment: maybe `$code = '$a - $b - $c <br>';` is available  outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

In your second example you have placed `$code = '$a - $b - $c <br>';` outside the loop, and as such the value will not change when looping through each row.

Whereas in you first example, it is placed within the loop, and as such the values of `$a`, `$b` and `$b` will be reassigned every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're changing $code inside the loop.

In the first iteration it equals "$a - $b - $c 
" but in the second iteration it's already been replaced.

Try to change:

```
$code = '$a - $b - $c <br>';
```

To:

```
$codeTemplate = '$a - $b - $c <br>';
```

and then inside the loop write it as:

```
eval("\$code = \"$codeTemplate\";");
```

EDIT:

However if you want to have the code that generates $code outside, maybe instead of eval() you could use a callback function?

For example, something like:

```
function query_select_array($table, $funcMakeCode) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if ($result = $this->myconn->query($query)) {
        while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $code = $funcMakeCode($obj);
            echo $code;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
}

...

query_select_array("tbl", function($obj) {
    $a = $obj->col1;
    $b = $obj->col2;
    $c = $obj->col3;
    return "{$a} - {$b} - {$c} <br>";
});
```

Comment: I was sure that I already tried that... but I tested again and... it's works!
That's becouse i was going crazy. Too much coding and not so much experience...
Thank you very much!